# How to do horizontal scrolling in a web browsrer by pixels?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, mouse, scrolling

Just pressing  right or left button is no good for me - it makes too big skips. Using mouse by clicking and dragging the slide bar is better, but still I have a feeling that my hand is too rough and it doesn't scroll by pixels. How can I do horizontal scrolling by pixels? I am especially interested in Firefox and Chrome browsers.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? I am asking because this sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Browsers are not designed for this, if you find yourself needing 1px precision when looking at a webpage you are probably using the wrong tool/

Comment: @terdon - (1) I have built a webpage on one hosting provider, and then built an identical webpage on another one. I have a feeling that the images on the second provider look a bit longer than their twins on the first one - despite the fact that I set up exactly the same width. So I decided to check upon it by means of opening two tabs, one for each provider's window, and by alternatively clicking on each one of the tabs. If the right edge of an image is constantly

Comment: @terdon - (2) moving  to the left and then back to the right while I am alternating, then the second provider really makes pics look longer. However, in order to perform this test I firstly need to place the left edge of both images in both tabs at the same imaginary vertical line (that is, at the same distance from the left edge of the screen). I have discovered that I just can't do it by means of usual horizontal strolling with a mouse.

Comment: Yeah, I thought you were trying to do something like that. There are some "smooth scrolling" addons out there but I doubt they can give 1px sensitivity, I'm not even sure the browser would be capable of it. I would just take two screenshots and compare them in an image editor.

Comment: @terdon - "I would just take two screenshots and compare them in an image editor" - WOW! Good idea! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome, I don't think there is a built-in way of single pixel scrolling.  An alternative you might try is what they call "auto-scrolling", which is smooth scrolling and not high velocity.  You hold down the middle mouse button or wheel and move the cursor in the direction you want the display to be moved.

Answer (score 0):

Hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> button and use the mouse wheel to scroll horizontally. This works universally, across browsers and platforms.

However, how quickly the mousewheel scrolls depends on the browser or the platform. Mostly, it is slower than the left/right keys. And often, there are settings that you can tweak.